# Sed from fish to bash

Tags: bash, sed, fish

I have a `providers.tf` containing content like:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  }
}
```

I need to replace the `region` as well as the `role_arn` dynamically.

With fish, the following expression works fine

```
REGION="eu-central-1"
ROLE_ARN="arn:iam:mnsasa:asssasa/codebuild"
sed -i "s/region = \"${var.region}\"/region = \"${REGION}\"/g" providers.tf
sed -i "s/role_arn = \"${var.role_arn}\"/role_arn = \"${ROLE_ARN}\"/g" providers.tf
```

However, in bash, I got the following error

```
s/region = "${var.region}"/region = "${REGION}"/g: bad substitution
```

Which I guess is due to character not being correctly escaped in `/bin/bash`.
So I went with escaping `{` and `$`

```
sed -i "s/region = \"\$\{var.region\}\"/region = \"${REGION}\"/g" providers.tf
```

Which gives me

```
sed -i 's/region = "$\{var.region\}"/region = "eu-central-1"/g' providers.tf
sed: -e expression #1, char 54: Invalid content of \{\}
```

Am I still missing some escaping here?

Ps - For Terraform people, I can't use variables here, because this is a pre-step of a `terraform import` commands which does not accept dynamic providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i 's~\(region = "\)\${var\.region}"~\1'"$REGION"'"~g; s~\(role_arn = "\)\${var\.role_arn}"~\1'"$ROLE_ARN"'"~g' providers.tf
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/DZ3juh):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  }
}'
REGION="eu-central-1"
ROLE_ARN="arn:iam:mnsasa:asssasa/codebuild"
sed 's~\(region = "\)\${var\.region}"~\1'"$REGION"'"~g; s~\(role_arn = "\)\${var\.role_arn}"~\1'"$ROLE_ARN"'"~g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:iam:mnsasa:asssasa/codebuild"
  }
}
```

In both commands, the part before a variable is quoted with single quotation marks, the variable is quoted with double quotation marks, and the rest is single-quote quoted.

Comment: Thanks! 
This gives me the following error
`sed -i 's/\(role_arn = "\)${var.role_arn}"/\1arn:iam:mnsasa:asssasa"/g' providers.tf
sed: -e expression #1, char 69: unknown option to `s' `

Comment: @Mornor I [tested](https://ideone.com/Bht1zp) it in Linux using your data, and it works. If you use it on Mac OS, you need to add `''` after `-i`., i.e. `sed -i '' 's/.../.../' file`

Comment: That's right. My bad, the example I gave was not 100% correct. For `role_arn`, a better example would be `arn:iam:mnsasa:asssasa/codebuild`. I've updated my example.

Comment: @Mornor Then simply change the delimiters, see the updated solution and demo.. Note you need to escape both dollar and `.` chars to make sure you match a literal `$` and `.` char.

Answer (score 2):

You went a step too far. Only the dollar sign `$` needs to be escaped in Bash.

```
"s/region = \"\${var.region}\"/region = \"${REGION}\"/g"
```

I'm not sure what the difference is with Fish since I don't use it.

---

By the way, you can combine the two `sed` commands into one.

Demo:

```
REGION="eu-central-1"
ROLE_ARN="arn:iam:mnsasa:asssasa"
sed "
    s/region = \"\${var.region}\"/region = \"${REGION}\"/g;
    s/role_arn = \"\${var.role_arn}\"/role_arn = \"${ROLE_ARN}\"/g
" << 'EOF'
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "${var.role_arn}"
  }
}
EOF
```

Output:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:iam:mnsasa:asssasa"
  }
}
```